# Rails 3: Predictive filtering (faceted navigation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ruby-on-rails-3, filter, faceted-search

Users can currently apply filters to a database query by setting checkboxes, e.g.

```
Colour
[] Red
[] Green
[] Blue    

Shape
[] Round
[] Square

Size
[] Small
[] Medium
[] Large
```

Clicking on a checkbox triggers an AJAX request which appends the `where` condition to the query, e.g.

```
@mymodel = MyModel.scoped
@mymodel = @mymodel.where(:colour => params[:colour]) if params[:colour]
...
```

What I would like to do now is add a count after each checkbox to indicate how many results would be displayed if a given checkbox is selected. e.g.

```
Colour
[] Red (148)
[] Green (121)
[] Blue (136)
...
```

Upon clicking a checkbox, the counts next to all checkboxes should be refreshed, and options pertaining to a zero result will not be displayed. This needs to work across all filter categories, so for example, if there is nothing small and red in the database, the 'Small' option should disappear when 'Red' is selected, and re-appear when it is deselected.

What is the best way to achieve this type of predictive filtering?

Many thanks.

**Update**
More specifically, my question is: What is the best way to implement faceted navigation in Rails?
(Thanks @Pasta for the identifying the term for this)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are quite a few open-source search engines that will give you faceted search.  We use [Thinking Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/) and have been very happy with it.  It looks like they have preliminary support for Rails 3, but it might be worth a shot.  The [facet syntax](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/facets.html) is fairly straightforward:

**Example:**

```
# This will return any search results for 'pancakes'
Article.search 'pancakes'

# This will return any facets for 'pancakes'
Article.facets 'pancakes'
```

You might also want to look at [Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/solr-ruby) and [Ferret](http://www.davebalmain.com/trac) -- both of which I believe support faceted search.

Comment: Thank you. Thinking Sphinx seems to offer exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Glad to help!  It's so much nicer than trying to roll your own (not to mention that there's a lot of documentation out there).

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [faceted search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faceted_search).

Cheers;

Comment: Thanks, I knew there must be a term for this type of filtering.

Answer (score 0):

although I can't answer fully, I suggest you look into updating this "form" or partial through ajax.  Ryan had a railscast 43 will give you a few ideas on how it can work, but then you can research how to do all the fancy stuff with jquery and rails3.

Comment: Thanks. Parts of the form are already being updated using AJAX. My question is how to get the filter counts in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a gem for ActiveRecord based filtering and facet calculation, that does not depend on external services/deamons: https://github.com/fortytools/forty_facets